# Display multiple images from a folder in a row

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I was able to display the first image in a label but what I'm looking for is to display all the images in the folder to be displayed side by side in a row and refresh the image automatically if there is any update. How can I create multiple labels and set images on it based on the number of image files in my folder. For example: if my folder contains image for Nicolascage, Tom Hanks, Sandra Bullocks then all their images should be placed in a row and if a new image replace the existing image then it should refresh automatically.

What I achieved so far:
[image]

My code:

```
import cv2,os
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from VideoFaceDetectiondup import vidcaptureface
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets #works for pyqt5

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, camera_index=0, fps=30):
        super().__init__()

        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index)
        self.dimensions = self.capture.read()[1].shape[1::-1]

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap(*self.dimensions)
        self.pixmapItem = scene.addPixmap(pixmap)

        view = QGraphicsView(self)
        view.setScene(scene)

        text = QLabel('facecam 1.0', self)
        label = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap("messigray_1.png")
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.show()
        # label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1270, 1280, 1200, 1200))   

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        layout.addWidget(text)
        layout.addWidget(label)



        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.setInterval(int(1000/fps))
        timer.timeout.connect(self.get_frame)
        timer.start()


    def get_frame(self):
        _, frame = self.capture.read()
        frame=vidcaptureface(frame)
        image = QImage(frame, *self.dimensions, QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.pixmapItem.setPixmap(pixmap)





app = QApplication([])
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: I don't know how to set multiple images from a folder in a row

Comment: Are you going to have only one row?

Comment: Yes just one row with maximum of 10 images

Comment: And what does OpenCV have to do with it? Is OpenCV relevant?

Comment: I'm doing some processing using opencv in the backend using that images

Comment: Why do you want to use QGraphicsView? Do you have something special about QGraphicsView for your purpose? I ask you because, for example, there is the option to use QScrollArea or QListWidget. On the other hand, how do you indicate the path of the image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181229/discussion-between-min2bro-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Windows Ten is my OS